# How to generate EDM diagram from localdb generated by Code First

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, ado.net-entity-data-model

I used code first to generate a database with four tables in it.  How can I view those tables in an Entity Data Model diagram? Here is the database that got created by Code First.

[image: SQL ServerObjectExplorer]

I tried clicking my project Add New Item... "ADO.NET Entity Data Model", "EF Designer from Database" and then it is asking me for a "Server Name" below.  What do I type here?

[image: Connection Properties]

I tried servername "(localdb)" and "localhost" and my machine name. None work. It just hangs a while and then says "The server was not found or was not accessible."

Answer (score 0):

Found it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542)!

The Server name is `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`
and the database name is `CodeFirst.QuestionnaireContext`